# Granularity of unit testing for grammar code

Tags: unit-testing

I have some grammatical code that does noun pluralization, adding articles to nouns, conjugating verbs, and so on.  Currently, there's just 4 test cases: `pluralizeSimpleNouns`, `pluralizeCompoundNouns`, `conjugateVerbs`, and `testArticles`.  Each of those test cases covers a bunch of different situations.  I *could* break it down so that each `assertEquals` is its own test case, resulting in `pluralizeEndsWithX`, `pluralizeEndsWithY`, `conjugateIsSecondPerson`, `conjugateIsThirdPersonSingular`, `conjugateIsThirdPersonPlural` and so on, but that would result in over 100 test cases, and I don't think the resulting test code would be as readable.

I was thinking of making it more granular by splitting off irregular grammar into their own test cases.  Would that be the right level of granularity for code like this?

Comment: That makes sense.  The question I'd ask is, "If a test fails, what will I need to fix?"  Assuming your "regular" routines exercise different code from your "irregular" routines, I think that's a very reasonable way to organize your tests.

Comment: does your testing framework have support for [parameterized tests](http://xunitpatterns.com/Parameterized%20Test.html)?  If so, that feature may let you split up the cases without hurting the readability of the code.